# ¿Se puede cambiar de idioma y frase la validación de Mercado Pago?

Tags: mercadopago

Al validar las tarjetas de crédito o cualquier error que venga de Mercado Pago, los errores se encuentran en inglés y dicen cosas por el estilo:

> 205   parameter cardNumber can not be null/empty

Me gustaría saber si Mercado Pago Devs tiene alguna forma oficial de cambiarlo o si se debe hacer a mano.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿has consultado la documentación de MercagoPago?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Si, consulte la documentación pero no encontré algo que me ayude. Por eso pregunto acá.

Comment: Brian, yo tampoco pude encontrar información al respecto, por lo que he creado una pregunta en el [GitHub de MercadoPago](https://github.com/mercadopago/code-examples/issues/15). Puedes seguir investigando y estar pendiente a la(s) respuestas en GitHub.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Genial, gracias. Estoy pendiente de las respuestas. Aunque espero que alguien acá pueda dar una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Los mensajes de error, corresponden al formato clásico codigo de error + descripción en ingles, para una interpretación global, su interpretación y las acciones a tomar dependen del desarrollador y la aplicación, por lo general no se suelen enviar directamente todos los mensajes de error de un API al usuario final.